# rake versions in different rvm gemsets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, osx-lion, rvm

I have created a `rvm 1.8.7` for running older rails projects.

When I run `rake`, there is a warning:

> WARNING: 'require 'rake/rdoctask'' is deprecated.  Please use 'require
>   'rdoc/task' (in RDoc 2.4.2+)' instead.

It's due to a newer version of `rake` is installed:

```
rake (0.9.2.2, 0.8.7)
```

by `rvm` in the `@global` gemset

```
$ gem list -d rake

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

rake (0.9.2.2, 0.8.7)
Author: Jim Weirich
Rubyforge: http://rubyforge.org/projects/rake
Homepage: http://rake.rubyforge.org
Installed at (0.9.2.2): /Users/horace/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358@global
             (0.8.7): /Users/horace/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358

Ruby based make-like utility.
```

If I try to delete `rake 0.9.2.2` in the `@global` gemset, there is a warning:

```
You have requested to uninstall the gem:
rake-0.9.2.2
rvm-1.11.3.3 depends on [rake (>= 0)]
If you remove this gems, one or more dependencies will not be met.
Continue with Uninstall? [Yn]
```

So, how can I use `rake 0.8.7` as default in my `rvm 1.8.7`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The gem wrappers for binaries let you specify which version of a particular program you want to run.  So you can go

```
rake _0.8.7_ [stuff]
```

Or, if you like you could modify the wrapper to use that version by default (but be careful about gems and rvm's that need the newer rake).  Change the line

```
version = ">= 0"
```

to

```
version = "= 0.8.7"
```

Comment: for `rvm` I don't know! try `which rake` or `type -p rake`?

Comment: Docs for this feature can be found in the gem docs:  `gem help install`